# Find Matrix of linear transformation L(V) = (3,-g,-g) x V (x is cross product)

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

[Click image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5G2b.png)

$$
L(V)=\begin{bmatrix}
3  \\
-g  \\   
-g  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\times  V
$$

($\times$ is cross product )
Anyone knows what is this supposed to mean? The question didn't even give what dimensions of V, I assume it's 1x3? since (3, -g,-g) is 3x1. But how am I supposed to determine unknown values if V is not known?

Click the image for a better view of the question

Comment: use mathjax instead of images

Comment: @cineel I hope that looks better

Comment: It is solution A) because it is the only one which is anti-symmetric as cross-product is.

Comment: Why transforming the $9$s into $g$s...? Besides, $\times$ is **cross** product.

Comment: Explanations https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1087003/305862

Comment: @Jean Marie Im sorry thanks for the help, I asked others the same qn and they told me it was a 9 too.... I misread it as a g